# WIll VR eliminate physical travel

Tags: technology

WIll VR eliminate physical travel such as commuting to work, holidays, road trips or going out with friends?

Comment: Suggest that more detail of the capabilities of the proposed VR in the world you are building is needed in order to answer this question meaningfully.  Is "VR" completely full-sensory and indistinguishable from "real" experience to the user?  How good are the communications supporting this? (unless comms are FTL there will be lag in interactions)

Comment: VR can't even eliminate its ability to make me vomit and get a migraine. What kind of VR are you speaking of?

Comment: Why do you think "eliminating physical travel" would get rid of holidays or going out with friends? In the real world, we can already hang out with our friends using VR (VRChat).

Comment: That's part of the plot of the movie Total Recall (best movie ever made). For poor people that want to visit Mars the dreams (vr) sold by Rekall Inc. are the best option.

Answer (score 3):

**Outside of a Small Subgroup of Antisocial Addicts, no**

I can already pump my system up full of chemicals that make me feel blissful and content all the time. So why am I even bothering participating in society and not currently at home mainlining a cocktail of psychotropic and psychedelic drugs into my veins? I can turn on my phone and find literally anyone to talk to, so why have real friends? I can hire a cam-girl to tell me that shes my girlfriend, and even possibly pay enough to have her meet me in person and follow me around to complete the delusion, so why am I even married?

These are all examples of behaviors that real people actually *DO* exhibit in the modern era. There are otaku in Japan who haven't left their apartments in years because a combination of video games, social media, pornography, and digital girlfriends do a significant enough job of stimulating those areas of the brain for a very specific subset of people to drop out of society to pursue them instead of reality.

I think it is safe to say that even with powerful fully immersive VR that VR addiction won't be seen at any higher rates than present day video-game addiction, or heroin addiction, or any other kind of addiction. Even at it's worst such individuals who are pursing methods of escape from reality full time at the total expense of their participation in society are a vast minority.

**Recent Evidence Suggest People More Interested with Authentic Experiences**

Millennials are the most wired in and commodified generation we have yet seen, most of them grew up with the current tech that we have immersed in an economy that is loaded with mass produced cheap goods. One might look to evidence that Millennials eat out at restaurants, go on cruises, and stay at resorts less than any other generation as evidence that they are at home with their thumbs busy on some little bit of digital escapism and munching down on artificially flavored fast food like the dirty entitled brats we all know they are. Dirty filthy young people, ignoring real socialization in favor of thier twitterbooks and face-sta-grams!

In fact, the opposite is true. Millennials are more likely to eat at home because they feel that it is a better way to get a real meal than paying $40 for a glorified walmart brand steak at sizzlers. Additionally enjoying a good meal at home with friends is far more attractive than being crowded into a noisy chain restaurant like cattle. They are buying less tickets for cruises and reserving fewer rooms at resorts, but they are traveling more. They are instead opting to venture off the beaten path and tacky canned tours of carefully groomed resorts in favor of finding their own real and authentic experiences. It is suggested that living in an age when a cheap imitation of something real is only a click or a credit card swipe away it creates a longing to experiencethe actual real deal. Millennials are paying out the nose to buy authentic clean, organic, locally sourced ingredients to eat at home because they are fed up with the artificilly flavored junk and tacky advertising laden restaurant atmospheres they grew up with. They are traveling to remote mountain villages to commune with shaolin monks because they don't like the idea of sitting on a boring bus while a fake theatrical announcer tells them probably made up anecdotes about them over the intercom. They don't want to hear it from a guide, they want to go see it and experience it themselves.

Of course the traditional restaurant and travel advisers are responding with marketing and media hit pieces to depict such behavior as pretentious and selfish, they are losing money. In reality it would appear that the farther you separate people from authentic experiences the harder they push back trying to obtain them. The perception is that as tech is evolving people are becoming hollow artificial husks who can't tell the real thing from the imitation. The actual reality is that this perception is manufactured. People are now more than ever attempting to seek out reality and authenticity.